# Competition question about rate of production

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is as follows:

X has a factory that manufactures drones. Each drone can produce paper clips. At time t minutes, the factory's production rate is 4t drones per minute and each drones production rate is 10t paperclip per minute. At any given moment, it is possible for there to be fractional quantities of drones and paper clips. If X starts with 0 drones and paperclips at t=0, how much paperclips will X have at t=5?

My first attempt is to integrate from 0 to 5 the expression 4t and 10t, which gives me 50 and 125 respectively. Then I try to multiply them to get $50\cdot 125$. However, I then realize that this cannot be the answer because the drones that are produced at the later stages doo not produce as fast as those that produce earlier at some time t<5. What operations can I do to find the average rate of production of each drone and the factory in the first 5 minutes?

What I guess is to draw a quadratic curve and obtain the area under the curve, which is 1/3 of the area of the rectangle if there is constant rate of production. Hence, my final answer is $\frac{50 \cdot 125}{3^2}$. I am not sure if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let there be $d(t)$ drones and $p(t)$ paperclips at time $t$.  We are told the drones are produced at $4t$ per minute so $$d(t)=\int_0^t4\tau d\tau=2t^2$$
Then we are told each drone produces $10t$ paperclips per minute, so 
$$p(t)=\int_0^td(\tau)10\tau d\tau=\int_0^t20\tau^3 d\tau=5t^4$$
And at $t=5$ there will be $50$ drones and $3125$ paperclips.